# Перевод уведомления «непонятна суть вопроса»

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия

Привет! Я модератор [дружественного](http://monoteism.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0.jpg) [сайта](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) «Русский язык», пришедший на эту замечательную Мету с мирным предложением: программисты — особая каста, с собственными понятиями, со своим жаргоном и т. д., и т. п.

Так случилось, что нашим сайтам приходится пользоваться одним и тем же переводом. Из-за этого некоторые выражения, уместные в среде программистов, выглядят вычурно для простых людей-непрограммистов. Один из показательных примеров — [текст](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262528?qt=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) уведомления, прикрепляемого к вопросу при закрытии по причине «непонятна суть вопроса». В нем содержатся:

1. словосочетание *«воспроизводить проблему»* («как её воспроизвести»), носящее специальный характер, и
2. неуместные для вопросов по русскому языку *«что вы хотите получить в результате»* и *«приведите пример кода»*.

Поскольку здесь куда больше переводчиков, чем на Мете РЯ, предлагаю найти компромисс.

Полные тексты:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s
>   hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to
>   Ask page for help clarifying
>   this question.

---

> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа
>   поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что
>   вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Без "примеров кода" будет тяжко (

Comment: @Nofate я понимаю!.. но жизнь... жизнь сложная штука

Comment: "например, приведите пример  текста или программного кода"

Comment: @strangeqargo: Это не скалируется :-(

Comment: На сегодняшний день, единственный выход – искать компромис. Во всей англоязычной сети состоящей из 150 сайтов используются одни и те же формулировки.

Comment: @Aer А можете задать такой же на главной мете? Возможно, что-то и поменяется, хотя бы в перспективе.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov это будет уже feature-request, потребуется большая поддержка, чтобы рассмотрели хотя бы (а ее не будет)

Comment: @Aer Да попробуйте:) Нас с русской меты пару десятков проголосуют, а там видно будет. А то так гарантированно придётся компромиссами давиться. Зато в любом случае репутации заработаете там. В крайнем случае всегда можно награду назначить, хотя бы 50.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну это уже не только РЯ касается, поэтому давайте текст вместе обдумывать

Comment: О чём думали разработчики, когда вводили одни понятия на весьма разные по направлениям сообщества? Теперь костыли нужно создавать.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что правильное решение проблемы — это завести разные переводы для разных сайтов. Разумеется, «воспроизводить проблему» нужно программистам, т. к. наш подсайт и создан для вопросов в формате «проблема — решение».

Я не знаю, как именно решают вопрос другие сайты, ведь у нас много разных сайтов и на английском языке. Возможно, имеет смысл позаимствовать решение оттуда.

---

Возможно, предложенное решение — долгосрочное, и в короткие сроки не реализуемо. Тем не менее, имеет смысл иметь разные переводы и, возможно, разные наборы причин закрытия. Пример: «Проблема вызвана опечаткой в исходном коде автора вопроса» — причина закрытия, очевидно, релевантная *только* для программистов.

---

**Обновление**: Николас [сообщил в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34451821#34451821), что англоязычные сайты используют одну и ту же формулировку. Так что к сожалению это решение не будет реализовано в ближайшем будущем. Так что всё же нужно придумывать формулировку, подходящую всем сайтам.

Comment: Дело в том, что предложенное вами решение об отдельных переводах для каждого из сайтов вряд ли получится реализовать, так как для этого нужно обращаться к разработчикам... а это очень долго, и не факт, что приведет к результату. Хотя, конечно, это лучшее решение. Так, скорее всего, нам придется искать хотя бы временный компромисс.

Comment: А ваш пример трогать не придется: для каждого сайта "не по теме, потому что..." индивидуальны.

Comment: @Aer: Ну так давайте выясним сначала, я не думаю, что сроки будут слишком большими, учитывая многочисленность сайтов сети: у кого-то такие же проблемы явно уже были.

Comment: @Aer: Заходите в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), поговорим с Николасом по этому поводу.

Comment: @VladD, у модераторов был свой чат, где можно напрямую спросить :)

Comment: Хорошо, буду время от времени заходить и читать.

Comment: Спрашивали Николаса уже, разработчики на 99% откажут, т.к. 150 англоязычных сайтов успешно пользуются одной формулировкой. Соотношение затрат на внедрение фичи и пользы от неё для сети в целом пока выглядит неоправданным.

Comment: `Проблема вызвана опечаткой в исходном коде автора вопроса` – а это можно в причины «не по теме», они как раз кастомные для каждого сайта.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, она вроде в не по теме и есть?

Comment: @Grundy у нас сейчас там вроде бы всего одна кастомная причина, остальные общие.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Ну я имел ввиду что причина опечатка, сейчас на экране - не по теме, при закрытии

Comment: @Grundy завтра посмотрю еще раз)

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что нам не нужно держаться за формулировки «приведите пример кода» и «воспроизведение проблемы». Как недавно обсуждалось, не в каждом вопросе должен быть пример кода. Много отличных вопросов можно задать без единой строчки кода.

Если вопросу не хватает именно кода для воспроизведения проблемы, то **нужно использовать другую причину закрытия: MCVE** (минимальный достаточный пример, воспроизводящий проблему).

Если вопросу не хватает смысла или формулировки желаемого результата, то нужно использовать причину «непонятна суть вопроса». Но тогда в ней не должно быть требования кода!

Выводы:

- Отсутствие возможности написать уникальный для каждого сайта текст в данной причине не является проблемой.
- Проблема в том, что вместо MVCE мы пытаемся использовать другую причину, для этого не предназначенную.

Решение: давайте использовать обе причины:  «непонятно, что вы спрашиваете» и MCVE — по назначению.

Answer (score 0):

Компромисс может быть просто в дословном переводе имеющегося текста:

> Пожалуйста, уточните в чём конкретно ваша проблема или добавьте дополнительные подробности для прояснения того, что вам требуется. В текущем виде трудно понять, о чём именно вы спрашиваете. Посмотрите страницу Справки «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения этого момента.

Главная причина такого подхода в первую очередь обусловлена тем, что наши сайты - это локализованные версии англоязычных, без каких-то особенных логик в поведении, поэтому локализация сообщений должна передавать исходный смысл, а не пытаться вносить чего-то нового.

Если разным сайтам нужные разные строки, то они и в оригинальной (англоязычной) формулировке должны быть разными. Это, конечно, будет лучшим вариантом. Но и в этом случае локализованное сообщение не должно вносить новый смысл или искажать смысл оригинального сообщения.

Comment: вроде от такого отказались из-за того, что с таким текстом можно любой вопрос закрывать

Comment: @Grundy додумывать в переводе что-то своё, что не было заложено в оригинальный текст, тоже не лучший вариант.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546/186999)

Comment: Да, как (плохой) вариант. Все равно придется как-то избавиться от кривого "посмотрите для прояснения этого момента" и т. п.

Comment: @Aer ну я не утверждаю, что должно быть добуквенно именно так как я написал, но главное, чтобы не было внесено чего-то такого, чего фактически не было в оригинале.

Comment: Перевод должен отражать смысл задуманного, а не содержать такое же количество слов или быть добуквенной копией. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию «[Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/)»

Comment: Поддерживаю. Пока мы не получили разные строки для разных сайтов, нужно применить компромиссное решение. Когда и если получим, вернем обратно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если для отражения смысла требуется добавлять нечто новое, чего даже отдаленно не было в оригинале (фраза про код), то нужно менять оригинал, а не перевод. Но так как оригинал описывает общий для всех сайтов случай, его перевод также должен описывать общий случай. Будь он сформулирован без учета особенностей ruSO при локализации, то вопроса от участника rusSE вовсе бы не возникло. Собственно, по Вашей ссылке ответ Squidward содержит те же мысли.